# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent relation Eager loading not working

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, eager-loading

I tried all the answers already on the forum, none helped me.

**App\User.php Model defines hasOne relationship**

```
public function apikey()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ApiKey', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

**App\ApiKey.php Model defines reverse relationship**

```
protected function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','user_id');
}
```

Now I have a transform function with is call from controller `return $this->response->withItem(**$users**, new UserTransformer);`

**App\Transformer\UserTransformer.php**

```
public function transform($resource) //$resource is a users object
{
    $user_id = (int) $resource->user_id;
    $apiKey = $resource->apikey->key;
    return [
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'apikey' => $apiKey
    ];
}
```

I get following error at `$apiKey = $resource->apikey->key;`

> Trying to get property of non-object

I do not understand where am I going wrong Please suggest.

Thanks,

K

Comment: in the response your passing a single user?

Comment: yes it's a single user passed. $users is a collection of users but in this situation it always will have only one user in it.

Comment: wow and there is no typo above? $this->response() the missing brackets

Comment: Well I am using chrisbjr/apigaurd and response is a property of that class. I checked dd($resource) and it is a proper user model object with a single user. I don't know why eager loading is erred.

Comment: Instead of `$user_id = (int) $resource->user_id;  $apiKey = $resource->apikey->key;` I did `$user_id = (int) $resource->user_id;    apiKey = ApiKey::find($user_id);` and it worked. But Still wondering why is eager loading not working. Any help appriciated

Comment: @karmendra You should try passing just a single model instead of `$users`. (Tip: use `first()` or `find()` when querying to get a single result)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Yes you are right, very silly of me didn't realize even after saying it my self that $resource is a collection of users and the eager loading will only work on user model. I tried `$resource->first()->apikey->key` and it worked. Thanks for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: @karmendra You're welcome. I copied my comment as an answer so you can accept it to mark your question as resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try passing just a single model instead of users.
You can use `first()` or `find()` when querying to get a single result.